# How to write the title of my presentation in a block in Beamer using Boadilla Theme

Tags: beamer

How do I put the title of my presentation in a block, in Boadilla Theme? The first few lines of my presentation looks like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\title{Equivalent forms of LUB Property}
\author{Saikat Goswami}

\institute
{
  \inst{Department of Mathematics} 
  Ramakrishna Mission Vidyamandira 
  Belur Math 
  shirsho112358@gmail.com
}

\date{\today} 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: What exactly does " put the title of my presentation in a block" mean here? Also, the title of your question mentions tht title of an article, while the question itself refers to the title of a presentations. You tagged your question using `beamerarticle`, but use `beamer` in your code example. Please clarify. What is `\inst` supposed to do here?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected my post now. What I want is to put the title of my presentation inside a blue box.

Comment: I don't know if I have correctly used "\inst" or not. But I used it because it made the font-size of "Department of Mathematics" relatively smaller than the size of "Ramakrishna Mission Vidyamandira". That is the reason I used it.

Comment: Depending on hoy dark the blue color shuld be, you could use `\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=author in head/foot}` or `\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=date in head/foot}`. (I'll add an answer later.)

Comment: @leandriis: I am using Beamer for the first time. So I don't know anything about it. I am learning. Your guidance will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please, always post the smallest code possible, but  always being a complete document compilable as is.   Guessing that you have also a `\maketitle` after your incomplete code ... What about `\usecolortheme{seahorse}` before `\title`, for instance?  It does not change only the color tile scheme, but maybe in the good direction.

Comment: @Fran:  How do write codes in boxes while commenting? I tried but could not do it.

Comment: In the comments  type the commands between grave accents, but do not include the code of the example in the comments. Edit our question to complete the code and save it again. In the question indenting with four spaces the code is formatted with a gray background. For a small piece of code within the text Ctrl-K  mark it with grave accents. Or use the  button. "{}"  in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `\setbeamercolor{title}{...}` to the preamble of your document in order to add a colored box with rounded corners and a drop shadow around the title on your title frame. Depending on the shade of blue you want to get, for example one of the three shades already present in the footer, you could use `\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=author in head/foot}` or one of the other two versions shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\title{Equivalent forms of LUB Property}
\author{Saikat Goswami}

\institute[]
{
  Department of Mathematics
   
  Ramakrishna Mission Vidyamandira
   
  Belur Math 
  
  shirsho112358@gmail.com
}

\date{\today} 

\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=author in head/foot}
%\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=title in head/foot}
%\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=date in head/foot}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The three versions will result in the following outputs:

[image][image][image]

---

Please note that I also slightly altered the argument(s)  of the `\institute` command in comparison to your original code. I added `[]` in order to prevent the institute from showing in the footer in which it would partially be hidden by the "title"  field. I also added blank lines to make sure, the 4 individual lines in the code are also shown in 4 lines in the resulting pdf file. Lastly, I also removed the `\inst` command, since it is usually used for multiple authors with different affiliations.

Comment: is it possible to make all of title, author, institute in one block ?